# How can I convert or display a XML format message to SOAP envelop format in C#.?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have a FIX (Financial Information Exchange) message format, e.g. `35=U1 49=GEMI1 8=FIX.4.1 9=732` or `8=FIX.4.1 9=751 35=U1 34=3 49=GEMI2 52=20160125-10:52:21`, which I converted to XML format.

```
<messageTags>
<tag key="9" value="751" />
<tag key="8" value="FIX.4.1" />
<tag key="35" value="U1" />
<tag key="34" value="3" />
<tag key="49" value="GEMI2" />
<tag key="52" value="20160125-10:52:21" />
</messageTags>
```

I want to convert or display this type of xml in a SOAP format like below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eu="http://client.ws.emx.co.uk">
 <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
<eu:processXmlMessageRequest>
<sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
<creationTime>2016-05-28T09:36:22.165</creationTime>
<messageTags>
        <tag key="8" value="FIX.4.1" />
        <tag key="9" value="751" />
        <tag key="35" value="U1" />
        <tag key="34" value="3" />
        <tag key="49" value="GEMI2" />
        <tag key="52" value="20160125-10:52:21" />
</messageTags>
<payloadType>XmlFixMessageTags</payloadType>
</eu:processXmlMessageRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anybody help on this, how to do it in Visual Studio C#.

Comment: Uhm ... not sure what exactly you are asking, but if you want to turn the XML from the top into the XML at the bottom ... just add the missing text (either as string literal or with an XmlWriter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement messageTags = XElement.Load(FILENAME);

            string header =
                "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:eu=\"http://client.ws.emx.co.uk\">" +
                     "<soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>" +
                     "<soapenv:Body>" +
                       "<eu:processXmlMessageRequest>" +
                       "</eu:processXmlMessageRequest>" +
                     "</soapenv:Body>" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";

            XElement envelope = XElement.Parse(header);
            XElement request = envelope.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "processXmlMessageRequest").FirstOrDefault();

            int sequenceNumber = 1;
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            request.Add(new object[] {
               new XElement("sequenceNumber", sequenceNumber),
               new XElement("creationTime", now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddT" + now.TimeOfDay.ToString())), //>2016-05-28T09:36:22.165</creationTime>
               messageTags 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting blank output, where should I see the output in SOAP format.

Comment: The xml is in envelope.  You can get a string as following : str envelopeStr = envelope.ToString()